# Create cookie on closing the browser window or tab

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a problem. I want to create a cookie in JavaScript and I do it like the following:
`document.cookie = "type=banner;expires=Thu, 25 Nov 2020 08:50:17 GMT";`
Now the problem is that when I close the browser I want this cookie to expire and also to create a new one just like this `document.cookie = "type=popup;expires=Thu, 25 Nov 2020 08:50:17 GMT";`

How can I achieve the following functionality in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can listen for the `beforeunload` event. This happens "when the window, the document and its resources are about to be unloaded." [BeforeUnloadEvent - Web APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeUnloadEvent). A cookie can be deleted by setting its `expires` to zero [Document.cookie - Web APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#notes). And then you can add the new one.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', e => {
  //"delete" the old cookie
  document.cookie = "type=banner;expires=0";
  //add the new cookie
  var expires = new Date();
  expires.setHours(expires.getHours()+2); // expires in two hours
  document.cookie = `type=popup;expires=${expires.toUTCString()}`;
});
```